# Compare two objects, and return string. But one object doesn't take parameters?

Tags: java, class, object

This is homework.

GOAL: I want to compare the date of two objects to decide whether my person object is an adult or not and store this in a string.

The strange thing is, all my values of date d1 are 0;

```
public class Date {

  public int day, month, year;  
  public String child

  Date(date d1, date d2) {
      if ((d1.year - d2.year > 18) ||
          ((d1.year  - d2.year == 18) && (d2.year> d1.year)) ||
          ((d1.year  - d2.year == 18) && (d2.year == d1.maand) && (d2.day > d1.day))) {
             child = adult;  
      } else {
            child = child;
  }

  Date(int a, int b, int c) {
    a = year;
    b = month; 
    c = day; 
  }

  Date (String birthdate) {
    String pattern = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
    boolean b = birthdate.matches(pattern);
    if (b) {
        String[] str = birthdate.split("-"); 
        for (String s: str)
            this.day = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            this.month = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            this.year = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
            this.child = false; 
    } else {
          System.out.println("Wrong format");
    } 

}
```

When I make a test, this happens:

> ```
>   System.out.println("D1 year = " + d1.year); 
>   System.out.println("D1 day = " + d1.day); 
>   System.out.println("D1 month = " + d1.month);
> ```

```
Result: 
D1 year = 0
D1 day = 0
D1 month = 0
```

Why does this happen? Lets look at my other class.

My other class, where my method infoPerson is located is as following:

```
    public static Person infoPerson() {

       String name, lastname, birthdate;  
       Datum birthday, today;  

       System.out.println("Firstname:");
       name = userInput();  
       System.out.println("Lastname:");
       lastname = userInput(); 
       System.out.println("Birthdate?:");
       birthdate = userInput(); 

       //here I send the string birthdate to my Date class
       birthday = new Date(birthdate); 
       today = new Date(3, 7, 2013); 


      //Here I want to compare my two Date objects, today and birthday. This is were I got stuck, how do I do this correctly?
      dateChild = new Date(today, birthday); 

      // here i send the new date to my Person class what consists of two strings and Data birthday
      return new Gast(name, lastname, dateChild); 

   }
```

Comment: How come this: `void compareTo(date d1, date d2)` works ?

Comment: Sorry, forget to edit this.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment in the constructor is reversed:

```
Date(int a, int b, int c) {
    a = year;    // should be year = a;
    b = month;   // month = b;
    c = day;     // day = c;
}
```

Please don't use the class name same as the one defined in Java API. `Date` is already a class in `java.util` package.

Apart from that there are many compiler errors in your code:

- `public string child` - isn't going to compile. Should be `String` not `string`.
- `void compareTo(date d1, date d2)` - I don't know what you're trying to do here. But this too won't compile. Undefined type - `date`
- You've declared the `Datum birthday` and initializing it using `new Date(...)`. That too wouldn't work.
- For some reason, I feel like you don't have any method in your class, but just a bunch of constructors. My suggestion would be - throw that code away, and start afresh.
- And please don't use a bunch of integer fields to store birthdays. Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instance instead.

Comment: OMG, I've been pondering for hours.

Comment: Yes: ive translated the code from a different language and had to type the code over by hand. Made some mistakes. I will edit this. 

Thanks :)

Comment: @swennemen Next time, please make sure that you post at least a compilable code if you claim that the code is running.

Comment: +1 This kind of "typo" errors i hate because they are hard to find out (you don't expect such a mistake:-)